# How to get the order id from $observer in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

i am developing a magneto component. I need to get the order id from the observer. I am using magneto 1.7.0.2. I have tried several methods already which found from Google. But non of them helped me. I can get order number description, name, price, etc..

the code i was finally testing was this,

```
    $order = $observer -> getEvent()-> getOrder(); 
    $id = $order -> getName();
```

Thank you very much....

this is the config of the observer : it is placed under globel

```
<events> 
  <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
             <observers>
                 <ModuleName>
                     <class>CompanyName_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>afterSalesOrderSaveCommitAfter</method>
                 </ModuleName>
             </observers>
  </sales_order_invoice_save_after>  
</events>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payex payment gateway is clearing the session after it does the payment. It also captures same event that i have used, this is the code which worked for me. Actually Sandeep is right.

```
    $session->setPayexQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
    $session->getQuote()->setIsActive(false)->save();
    $session->clear();
```

thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
$id = $order -> getId();`

This would work. Worked for me. Actually you were passing invoice to event and checking for order. :)

Comment: thank you very much... i have found the anwer finally, you were right but in my case payex payment gateway is clearing the session. i got it as they below.

Comment: Ok that was good that you got what was required. 
Please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

**Try**
`order->getData('increment_id')`
 **or**
`$order->getData('entity_id')`

Comment: no it didnt work. returned me the following error from that line. Call to a member function getData() on a non-object, why getData is not working?? thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Can you print your
 $observer -> getEvent()-> getOrder();
and check
I dont think observer is getting your order

Comment: no i cant print that. that is the issue i am having. thnaks for the support... plz help

Comment: ok can u just print get_class($observer -> getEvent()-> getOrder())

Comment: it returned the component that i wrote: eg CompnyName_ComponentName_Model_Observer.

Comment: Give me the config code for observer
actually the observer is not set on any event which would get order I think so